# A topology on a set $X$ is exactly determined by specifying when, for $x\in X$ and sequences $x_n \in X, x_n \to x, $ as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

A topology on a set $X$ is exactly determined by specifying when, for $x\in X$ and sequences $x_n \in X, x_n \to x, $ as $n \to \infty$.

This is a statement from my functional analysis notes, but I don't really understand why this is true. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can show how this characterization is true.

Comment: A set $A$ is open iff no sequence of points _outside_ $A$ converges to a point _in_ $A$.

Comment: We're assuming first-countable spaces here, I take it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This holds for first countable or sequential spaces. It need not hold, even within functional analysis (the dual of $L^\infty([0,1])$ does not obey it, IIRC).

For first countable spaces there is a simple theorem: $A \subseteq X$ is closed iff for all sequences $(x_n)$ that converge to $x$, if all $x_n$ are from $A$, then also $x \in A$. I.e. $A$ is closed under sequential limits.

The closed sets of course determine the topology (the open sets are their complements).

But like I said, not really true for all topological spaces.

Comment: An even simpler (counter)example is $\ell^1$ equipped with the weak topology. A sequence converges weakly in $\ell^1$ iff(!) it converges strongly.

Comment: This is sometimes called the *Schur property* of $\ell^1$.